# How do I ignore extra input integers

Tags: c++

I've been building a menu for class, and I can't figure out how to stop calculations and output an error message when more inputs are given than asked for. This is a snippet of what I have(val1 and val2 are unsigned long int and inputError is a boolean):

```
          case '&':
                std::cout << "Enter values for first and second operand:" << std::endl;
                std::cin >> val1 >> val2;
                inputError = 0;
                checkData1(val1, val2, inputError);
                if (inputError) {
                    continue;
                }
                else {
                    result = val1 & val2;
                    std::cout << "Result: " << result;
                    std::cout << " [Hexadecimal: " << std::setw(bitsize) << std::hex << result << std::dec << "]" << std::endl;
                }
                break;
```

This is the void function (checkData1):

```
    void checkData1(unsigned long int val1, unsigned long int val2, bool& inputError) {
    if (std::cin.fail()) {
        inputError = 1;
        std::cout << "Input error, enter choice and values again." << std::endl;
        std::cin.clear();
        while (std::cin.get() != '\n') {
            continue;
        }
    }
    else if ((int)val1 < 0 || (int)val2 < 0) {
        inputError = 1;
        std::cout << "Input error, enter choice and values again." << std::endl;
    }
}
```

And this is what I get:

```
Enter one of the following choices:
& - AND
| - OR
^ - XOR
~ - NOT
- - Negate
< - Left shift(logical shift only)
> - Right shift(logical shift only)
# - stop execution

&

Enter values for first and second operand:

1 2 3

Result: 0 [Hexadecimal:        0]
Enter one of the following choices:
& - AND
| - OR
^ - XOR
~ - NOT
- - Negate
< - Left shift(logical shift only)
> - Right shift(logical shift only)
# - stop execution
Invalid choice 3, please try again.
Enter one of the following choices:
& - AND
| - OR
^ - XOR
~ - NOT
- - Negate
< - Left shift(logical shift only)
> - Right shift(logical shift only)
# - stop execution
```

Instead of doing the calculations with the first two integers and giving an error with the third, I want it to ignore all of it, and put out an error message instead.

Comment: You might consider reading a full line with `getline` and then using a `stringstream` to extract the values. If the stream isn't at `eof` after you've extracted the expected number of values or has an error while extracting the values you can discard that input and raise an error. If `checkData1` returned a value to indicate success or failure it would probably help.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to checkData1. This uses the cin.peek function to check if there's anything other than a new line character in the cin buffer, and if so it sets the error variable and clears out the buffer

```
void checkData1(unsigned long int val1, unsigned long int val2, bool& inputError) {
    if (std::cin.fail()) {
        inputError = 1;
        std::cout << "Input error, enter choice and values again." << std::endl;
        std::cin.clear();
        while (std::cin.get() != '\n') {
            continue;
        }
    }
    else if ((int)val1 < 0 || (int)val2 < 0) {
        inputError = 1;
        std::cout << "Input error, enter choice and values again." << std::endl;
    }
    if(std::cin.peek() != '\n'){
        inputError = 1;
        std::cout << "Make sure to only put in two numbers" << std::endl;
        while (std::cin.get() != '\n') {
            continue;
        }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to checkData1. This uses the cin.peek function to check if there's anything other than a new line character in the cin buffer, and if so it sets the error variable and clears out the buffer

```
void checkData1(unsigned long int val1, unsigned long int val2, bool& inputError) {
    if (std::cin.fail()) {
        inputError = 1;
        std::cout << "Input error, enter choice and values again." << std::endl;
        std::cin.clear();
        while (std::cin.get() != '\n') {
            continue;
        }
    }
    else if ((int)val1 < 0 || (int)val2 < 0) {
        inputError = 1;
        std::cout << "Input error, enter choice and values again." << std::endl;
    }
    if(std::cin.peek() != '\n'){
        inputError = 1;
        std::cout << "Make sure to only put in two numbers" << std::endl;
        while (std::cin.get() != '\n') {
            continue;
        }
    }
    
}
```